# Healtcheck url not working: Cannot match any routes

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am working on a .net Core 2.2/Angular 8 application.
I've heard about the HealthCheck and I wanted to implement it in my application.
 Here is my Startup.cs:

```
    using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    namespace OnlineXmlTools
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSwaggerDocument();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
        });
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            // Set Cookie properties using CookieBuilder properties†.
            options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
            options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
            options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
        });
        services.AddHealthChecks();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Register the Swagger generator and the Swagger UI middlewares
        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
        app.UseHealthChecks("/healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });
    }
}
```

}

When I start my application (https://localhost:44328/), I try to reach the healthcheck URL as described in the middleware:
        https://localhost:44328/healthcheck
It is supposed to show information.
Instead, I have this error:
        ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'healthcheck'

Did I miss something ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipeline order is not correct it should be like this

```
        app.UseHealthChecks("/healthcheck");

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was it.
But why UseSpa should bet at the end ?

Comment: because your spa have to be default fallback. If you put your health check route at the end .net core will think that route is angular route